# Начало и конец

Tags: adobe, dreamweaver

Использую в работе `Adobe Dreamweawer CS4` и частенько сталкиваюсь с проблемой при работе с чужим кодом:
Непонятно в каком месте начинается блок DIV и где он заканчивается.
Можно ли как-то визуально показать принадлежность?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используйте Dreamweawer) Есть IDE более удобные в использовании.